# excel how to find the default file extension

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I'm trying to write and application that creates excel files using python and pywin32 and I'd like to save the file using the default format and extension for whatever version of excel the user is using. Depending on the version of excel they are using the default format could be "Open XML Workbook" which uses the ".xlsx" extension. Other times it could be the basic excel format and ".xls" extension. Plus the user can configure excel to use some other default format.

I know how to find the default format (Application.DefaultSaveFormat) - but I can't figure out how to determine the default extension for that format. Part of the problem is that my file names tend to include periods even before the extension:
the basic file name is "filename.BOM" so the actual file name should be "filename.BOM.xls" or "filename.BOM.xlsx" depending on the default format.

If I didn't have the double period in the file name everything would be fine.
So if the default format is "Open XML Workbook" Workbook.SaveAs( "filename") would create a file named "filename.xlsx". But Workbook.SaveAs( "filename.BOM") creates a file named exactly "filename.BOM". Excel does not add the default extension when it sees a period already in the file name.

The only thing I can figure out is to save a temporary file, get the extension from that, then delete the temporary file - but that seems really kludgey. Anyone have a better solution?

```
from tempfile import mktemp
from os import path
from os import remove as delfile
class excel:
    def __init__( self):
        self.app = DispatchEx( "Excel.Application" )
    def saveas_default_ext_format( self, workbook, filename):
        # filename - file name with path but without extension

        tmpname = mktemp()

        alerts = self.app.DisplayAlerts
        self.app.DisplayAlerts = False
        workbook.SaveAs( tmpname)
        self.app.DisplayAlerts = alerts

        tmpname = self.app.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        x, ext = path.splitext( tmpname)
        fullname = filename + ext
        workbook.SaveAs( fullname)

        delfile( tmpname)

        return fullname
```

Comment: Use `.xls`, all versions of Excel will honor it.

Comment: Instead of deleting the temp file and saving it again under a different name, why not just rename it?

Comment: "Instead of deleting the temp file, why not just rename it?" - because you cannot rename or delete a file as long as excel has it open as excel has a lock on the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make a dict of xlfileformats:extensions and use that to do a lookup:

```
from tempfile import mktemp
from os import path
from os import remove as delfile
class excel:
    def __init__( self):
        self.app = DispatchEx( "Excel.Application" )
        self.dct =     {51:'xlsx',
                        52:'xlsm',
                        50:'xlsb',
                        56:'xls'
                        }

    def saveas_default_ext_format( self, workbook, filename):
        # filename - file name with path but without extension


        fullname = '.'.join((filename, self.dct[self.app.DefaultSaveFormat]))
        workbook.SaveAs( fullname)

        return fullname
```

I've only included the most common formats in the sample dict, but you can flesh it out from a number of sources on the web, like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat).  I didn't put in an KeyError exception handler, but you'll probably want one.

good luck, 
Mike

Comment: I was looking for a more direct way of looking up the extension. However, I think this is cleaner than saving a temporary file. P.S. The link you provided shows the enumeration of each format but does not give the extension. I've searched and a table that shows both is a bit hard to find - which is odd. I'll sort that out though. Thanks Mike

Comment: Yes, you have to figure the extension from the xlFileFormat constant, a list is hard to find.  But once you build your dict, then you've got it.

Answer (score 4):

Since a list containing the enumerations, values and extensions all in one place is hard to find, here the way I did it. The tricky part is getting the enumerations to work (see the code)

```
import win32com
from os.path import splitext

XlFileFormats = [ 
    'xlAddIn'                      , # Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Add-In
    'xlAddIn8'                     , # Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Add-In
    'xlCSV'                        , # CSV
    'xlCSVMac'                     , # Macintosh CSV
    'xlCSVMSDOS'                   , # MSDOS CSV
    'xlCSVWindows'                 , # Windows CSV
    'xlCurrentPlatformText'        , # Current Platform Text
    'xlDBF2'                       , # DBF2
    'xlDBF3'                       , # DBF3
    'xlDBF4'                       , # DBF4
    'xlDIF'                        , # DIF
    'xlExcel12'                    , # Excel12
    'xlExcel2'                     , # Excel2
    'xlExcel2FarEast'              , # Excel2 FarEast
    'xlExcel3'                     , # Excel3
    'xlExcel4'                     , # Excel4
    'xlExcel4Workbook'             , # Excel4 Workbook
    'xlExcel5'                     , # Excel5
    'xlExcel7'                     , # Excel7
    'xlExcel8'                     , # Excel8
    'xlExcel9795'                  , # Excel9795
    'xlHtml'                       , # HTML format
    'xlIntlAddIn'                  , # International Add-In
    'xlIntlMacro'                  , # International Macro
    'xlOpenDocumentSpreadsheet'    , # OpenDocument Spreadsheet
    'xlOpenXMLAddIn'               , # Open XML Add-In
    'xlOpenXMLTemplate'            , # Open XML Template
    'xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled', # Open XML Template Macro Enabled
    'xlOpenXMLWorkbook'            , # Open XML Workbook
    'xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled', # Open XML Workbook Macro Enabled
    'xlSYLK'                       , # SYLK
    'xlTemplate'                   , # Template
    'xlTemplate8'                  , # Template 8
    'xlTextMac'                    , # Macintosh Text
    'xlTextMSDOS'                  , # MSDOS Text
    'xlTextPrinter'                , # Printer Text
    'xlTextWindows'                , # Windows Text
    'xlUnicodeText'                , # Unicode Text
    'xlWebArchive'                 , # Web Archive
    'xlWJ2WD1'                     , # WJ2WD1
    'xlWJ3'                        , # WJ3
    'xlWJ3FJ3'                     , # WJ3FJ3
    'xlWK1'                        , # WK1
    'xlWK1ALL'                     , # WK1ALL
    'xlWK1FMT'                     , # WK1FMT
    'xlWK3'                        , # WK3
    'xlWK3FM3'                     , # WK3FM3
    'xlWK4'                        , # WK4
    'xlWKS'                        , # Worksheet
    'xlWorkbookDefault'            , # Workbook default
    'xlWorkbookNormal'             , # Workbook normal
    'xlWorks2FarEast'              , # Works2 FarEast
    'xlWQ1'                        , # WQ1
    'xlXMLSpreadsheet'             , # XML Spreadsheet
    ]

xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch( "Excel.Application")
'''if you use Dispatch( 'Excel.Application') without having run makepy first,
    the constants from XlFileFormats will not be available.
    See
    http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/GeneratedSupport.html
    http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html
    '''
app = xl.Application
app.Visible = 1
book = app.Workbooks.Add(); book.Activate()
print 'DefaultSaveFormat:', app.DefaultSaveFormat

# you cannot access the constants until AFTER you have dispatched excel
constants = win32com.client.constants

print
app.DisplayAlerts = False
for formatName in XlFileFormats:
    formatNum = getattr( constants, formatName)
    print '%-35s: %5d,' % ( formatName, formatNum),
    try: book.SaveAs( r'C:\excel_file_formats\xlbook', formatNum)
    except Exception: print 'could not save this format'
    else:
        wbname, wbext = splitext( book.Name)
        print '"%s"' % ( wbext)
        del wbname, wbext
    #~ raw_input( '    paused')

app.Quit()
```

Here is the output:

```
DefaultSaveFormat: 51

xlAddIn                            :    18, ".xls"
xlAddIn8                           :    18, ".xls"
xlCSV                              :     6, ".csv"
xlCSVMac                           :    22, ".csv"
xlCSVMSDOS                         :    24, ".csv"
xlCSVWindows                       :    23, ".csv"
xlCurrentPlatformText              : -4158, ".txt"
xlDBF2                             :     7, could not save this format
xlDBF3                             :     8, could not save this format
xlDBF4                             :    11, could not save this format
xlDIF                              :     9, ".dif"
xlExcel12                          :    50, ".xlsb"
xlExcel2                           :    16, could not save this format
xlExcel2FarEast                    :    27, could not save this format
xlExcel3                           :    29, could not save this format
xlExcel4                           :    33, could not save this format
xlExcel4Workbook                   :    35, could not save this format
xlExcel5                           :    39, ".xls"
xlExcel7                           :    39, ".xls"
xlExcel8                           :    56, ".xls"
xlExcel9795                        :    43, could not save this format
xlHtml                             :    44, ".htm"
xlIntlAddIn                        :    26, could not save this format
xlIntlMacro                        :    25, could not save this format
xlOpenDocumentSpreadsheet          :    60, ".ods"
xlOpenXMLAddIn                     :    55, ".ods" !!! this one is not right !!!
xlOpenXMLTemplate                  :    54, ".xltx"
xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled      :    53, ".xltm"
xlOpenXMLWorkbook                  :    51, ".xlsx"
xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled      :    52, ".xlsm"
xlSYLK                             :     2, ".slk"
xlTemplate                         :    17, ".xlt"
xlTemplate8                        :    17, ".xlt"
xlTextMac                          :    19, ".txt"
xlTextMSDOS                        :    21, ".txt"
xlTextPrinter                      :    36, ".prn"
xlTextWindows                      :    20, ".txt"
xlUnicodeText                      :    42, ""
xlWebArchive                       :    45, ".mht"
xlWJ2WD1                           :    14, could not save this format
xlWJ3                              :    40, could not save this format
xlWJ3FJ3                           :    41, could not save this format
xlWK1                              :     5, could not save this format
xlWK1ALL                           :    31, could not save this format
xlWK1FMT                           :    30, could not save this format
xlWK3                              :    15, could not save this format
xlWK3FM3                           :    32, could not save this format
xlWK4                              :    38, could not save this format
xlWKS                              :     4, could not save this format
xlWorkbookDefault                  :    51, ".xlsx"
xlWorkbookNormal                   : -4143, ".xls"
xlWorks2FarEast                    :    28, could not save this format
xlWQ1                              :    34, could not save this format
xlXMLSpreadsheet                   :    46, ".xml"
```

I don't know why it can't save some of the formats; but they don't seem like ones that would be very common or useful.

Also, the xlOpenXMLAddIn format is very odd. It reports and extension of ".ods" - but that is not what it actually saves. If you delete any files that you have created, then alter the code to run just once with the xlOpenXMLAddIn format

```
import win32com
from os.path import splitext
from time import sleep

xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch( "Excel.Application")
app = xl.Application
app.Visible = 1
book = app.Workbooks.Add(); book.Activate()
constants = win32com.client.constants

formatName = 'xlOpenXMLAddIn'
formatNum = getattr( constants, formatName)
print 'test_file_format: %s > %s' % ( formatName, formatNum)

app.DisplayAlerts = False
try: book.SaveAs( r'C:\excel_file_formats\xlbook', formatNum)
except Exception: print 'could not save this format'
else:
    wbname, wbext = splitext( book.Name)
    print '"%s" > "%s"' % ( wbname, wbext)
```

You get this:

```
test_file_format: xlOpenXMLAddIn > 55
"Book1" > ""
```

The file that it creates will be named "xlbook.xlam"; but the title bar of excel says "Book1 - Microsoft Excel". So I'm not sure what is going on with this on. It doesn't seem like a very useful format at any rate.